# Facebook webhook does not trigger via native app

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have configured the Facebook Webhook of my app, that it sends a call when a change has happened on my (user)feed. When I post something on Facebook via my laptop or mobile browser, the Webhook triggers.
But when I post something via the native iOS app, it doesn't trigger.

Does anyone have an idea about this?

Comment: I see no reason why how a post was made should make any difference. Suggest you go file a bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Ok thanks. Shots fired: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1753520691593095/